# Reacting to BLE directed advertising (ADV_DIRECT_IND) in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

How to react to **directed advertising** (`ADV_DIRECT_IND == 0001`) in Android?

There is a BLE-gadget which sends directed advertising to an Android phone (using hardcoded MAC address of the phone for now) and in my Android app I would like to react and to initiate a connection to the gadget and read the [org.bluetooth.characteristic.location_and_speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967357/how-to-extract-latitude-and-longitude-from-location-and-speed-characteristic) value from the gadget:

[image: screenshot]

Please advise if it's possible by the means of [Android 5 API](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android/bluetooth).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Direct advertising* does work - at least with *HTC M8* phone and Android 5.0 (API level 21 and higher).

The solution has been to add the device addresses to the [ScanFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanFilter.html).

If you leave the filters empty, the scanning callbacks won't be called.

Here my working code:

```
public static final String TAG = "My_BLE_app";

public static final String DEVICE_1 = "D4:BE:84:72:5B:8E";
public static final String DEVICE_2 = "C4:39:07:19:60:E2";

private Context mContext;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothLeScanner mScanner;
private ScanSettings mSettings;
private List<ScanFilter> mFilters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
```

First the method for initializing BLE:

```
public boolean init() {
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        return false;

    mScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    mSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();

    mFilters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(DEVICE_1).build());
    mFilters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(DEVICE_2).build());

    return mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
}
```

And then the scanning callbacks:

```
private ScanCallback mDirectedScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        processResult(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        for (ScanResult result: results) {
            processResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void processResult(ScanResult result) {
        BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
        if (device == null)
            return;

        String address = device.getAddress();
        if (!BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(address))
            return;

        int rssi = result.getRssi();

        Log.d(TAG, "address=" + address + ", rssi=" + rssi);

        // TODO connect to the device in under 1 second
    }
};
```

Finally the code to start the scanning:

```
mScanner.startScan(mFilters, mSettings, mDirectedScanCallback);
```

One question is still open though:

I don't know **how to detect the type of scan at the Android side - that is if the scan was directed or not**.

Answer (score 1):

To partially answer the open question:
I've noticed that the `ScanRecord.getBytes()` is empty - all '\0' - for a directed scan (`ADV_DIRECT_IND`) - but would contain the advertising data otherwise (`ADV_IND`).